# Lebesgue measurable function question

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $f$ be L measurable on [0,1] with $f(x)>0$ a.e. Suppose $A_{n}$ is a sequence of measurable sets in [0,1]. Prove that if
$\lim_{n \to\infty} \int_{A_{n}}^{ } f(x) dx=0 $ then $\lim_{n\to\infty}  \lambda{(A_{n})} =0 $

I am new to measure theory and couldn't find how to start. May I have a help,please?

Thank you

Comment: Who is $\lambda$?

Comment: Is $\lambda$ Lebesgue measure? $\lambda$ is not defined in your question, and it kinda appears out of nowhere.

Comment: It is not explained in the question. I couldn't also understand the relation with $\lambda$ and $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to show that $\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\lambda(A_n)}<\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$. To do so, fix $\epsilon>0$. Then there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $E_{\delta} = \{x\in[0,1]:f(x)\le\delta\}$, then $\lambda(E_{\delta})<\epsilon$ (why?). Now, let $B_n^{\delta} = A_n\backslash E_{\delta}$. Since $A_n\backslash B_n^{\delta}\subset E_{\delta}$, we have $\lambda(A_n\backslash B_n^{\delta})<\epsilon$. So it suffices to show that $\lambda(B_n^{\delta})\rightarrow 0$. Now
$$\int\limits_{A_n}{f(x)\text{ d}x}\ge\int\limits_{B_n^{\delta}}{f(x)\text{ d}x}\ge\int\limits_{B_n^{\delta}}{\delta\text{ d}x}.$$
(Why is the last inequality true?) Can you conclude from here?

Comment: I couldn't understand this part:
there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $E_{\delta} = \{x\in[0,1]:f(x)\le\delta\}$, then $\lambda(E_{\delta})<\epsilon$

Comment: I assume $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure here. For integers $n$, if we let $F_n = E_{1/n}$ (as defined above), then $F_{n+1}\subseteq F_n$ (why?), and $\cap_n{F_n}$ is the set of $x$ such that $f(x)\le\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n$, i.e. $f(x)\le 0$. By the hypothesis, this set has measure zero. Since $F_1$ has finite measure (it is a subset of $[0,1]$), we have $0 = \lambda\left(\cap_n{F_n}\right) = \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\lambda(F_n)}$. This means that there is some $n$ such that  $\lambda(F_n)<\epsilon$, so choosing $\delta = \frac{1}{n}$ gives $\lambda(E_{\delta})<\epsilon$.

Comment: Thank you. And from the final (at your answer) I will take limit and it'll give me $\lambda (B_{n}^{\delta})\rightarrow 0$
Since $\lambda (A_{n}- B_{n}^{\delta})< \epsilon$ we get $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \lambda (A_n )< \epsilon$ and $\epsilon$ is arbitary will give the answer. 
Am I right?

Comment: More or less. Technically, saying $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\lambda(A_n)}<\epsilon$ is incorrect, since we don't know beforehand if the limit actually exists. However, we can say that the $\limsup$ (which exists for every sequence) of $\lambda(A_n)$ does exist and is less than $\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon>0$. This implies that $\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\lambda(A_n)}\le 0$. The only way a $\limsup$ of a nonnegative sequence is nonpositive is if the limit of the sequence exists and is equal to zero (you should check this).

Comment: One more question:
We defined $E_{\delta} = \{x\in[0,1]:f(x)\le\delta\}$ and found 
$$\int\limits_{B_n^{\delta}}{f(x)\text{ d}x}\ge\int\limits_{B_n^{\delta}}{\delta\text{ d}x}.$$
I think they must change place (since $f(x)\le\delta$ )?

Comment: No. Since $B_n^{\delta} = A_n\backslash E_{\delta}$, $B_n^{\delta}$ consists of the points in $A_n$ which are *not* in $E_{\delta}$, i.e. points where $f(x)>\delta$.